# Flutter: firebase authorization flow won't work with routes

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, firebase-authentication, authorization

I'm trying to make sure that app-users that aren't authorised (signed in), are directed to the sign in page. This is what my `main.dart` looks like:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.active) {
          // some loading widget 
          return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(),);
        }
        FirebaseUser user = snapshot.data;
        if (user == null) {
          return MaterialApp(home: SignIn(),);
        }
        // this is the main app
        return MaterialApp(
          initialRoute: '/',
          routes: {
            '/': (context) => HomeScreen(),
            '/new_game': (context) => NewGame(),
            '/join_session': (context) => JoinSession(),
            '/my_rankings': (context) => MyRankings(),
            '/settings': (context) => Settings(),
          },
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

When I run the app (on chrome using the web function) I start of at the sign in page (as expected) which just contains an anonymous sign in button. When I sign in it gives an error, stating that the initial-route-builder (route `'/'` with `HomeScreen()` as builder) returns `null`. When I swap my the main app for a simple

`return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: Text('This Works')));`

it does seem to work. When using a simple `MaterialApp()` that does the same but using `routes`, it gives the error again, so the problem seems to be the routing. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think it will work like that. the main.dart should be used only as the app entry point.

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
```

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => SplashScreen(),
        '/home': (context) => HomeScreen(),
        '/new_game': (context) => NewGame(),
        '/join_session': (context) => JoinSession(),
        '/my_rankings': (context) => MyRankings(),
        '/settings': (context) => Settings(),
      },
    );
  }
```

}

class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {

```
void isLogged StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.active) {
      // some loading widget 
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
    }
    FirebaseUser user = snapshot.data;
    if (user == null) {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/SignIn');
    }
    // this is the main app
);

initiatState(){
    isLogged();
}

Widget build(BuildContext context){

}
```

}

> You could use this method to check if a user is logged auth.currentUser() it returns null if the user is not signed

```
 FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
await auth.currentUser() == null ? false : true;
```

Comment: I always hated when people return `something ? true : false`.
I'll say that it's more readable and a better practice to make beter boolean conditions such as `await auth.currentUser() != null`

Comment: This solution only resolves the "on launch" part and not the "account disabled while logged in" part. On launch, you check if the user is logged in, but if the refreshToken is disabled by `admin.auth().revokeRefreshTokens()`, the user will just run into an error & break the app. Further, on each `Scaffold` type widget, you will need to check `currentUser != null` which causes code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this!

```html
import 'package:base_app/screens/auth/login/index.dart';
import 'package:base_app/screens/boarding/index.dart';
import 'package:base_app/screens/main/home/index.dart';
import 'package:base_app/screens/main/profile/index.dart';
import 'package:base_app/screens/splash/index.dart';
import 'package:base_app/style/palette.dart';
import 'package:base_app/style/theme.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Sizer(
      builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            fontFamily: 'DancingScript',
            textTheme: getTextTheme(context),
            primarySwatch: colorRed as MaterialColor,
          ),
          home: LandingFlow(),
          routes: {
            ProfileScreen.id: (context) => ProfileScreen(),
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class LandingFlow extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LandingFlowState createState() => _LandingFlowState();
}

class _LandingFlowState extends State<LandingFlow> {
  bool isSplashOver = false;
  bool hasBoardingScreensShown = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isSplashOver) {
      if (hasBoardingScreensShown) {
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }

            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              debugPrint('HomeScreen');
              return HomeScreen();
            } else {
              debugPrint('LoginScreen');
              return LoginScreen();
            }
          },
        );
      }
      return BoardingScreen();
    }

    return SplashScreen(
      onFinished: () => setState(() {
        isSplashOver = true;
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

And for your `Splash Screen`:

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const id = 'SplashScreen';

  final Function onFinished;

  const SplashScreen({this.onFinished});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 3),
      () => onFinished(),
    );
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Splash Screen'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```